# Codeigniter-3 call stored procedure returns null

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Im using a Stored Procedure in MySQL that retrieve some information.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateAndSelect()
BEGIN
    Update Buddy set Buddy.winner = true, Partner.number = @number := Partner.number
    WHERE Buddy.winner is false
    ORDER BY RAND()
    LIMIT 1;

   SELECT p.number, Buddy.email
    FROM sorteo
    INNER JOIN Partner p on Buddy.id_buddy= p.id
    WHERE number= @number
    LIMIT 1;
END;
```

The data return a Select with just the number and the email.

However when i execute the call in CodeIgniter 3, the result is always NULL.

and right now im doing it this way.

```
function getData(){
    $result = $this->db->query("CALL UpdateAndSelect()");
         if ($result->num_rows() == 1) {
           return $result->result();
         } else {
           return false;
         }
}
```

Please anyone knows how can i fetch the data obtained from the StoredProcedure.

This is the result set that i obtain from MySQL. Note: number = numero
[image]

Answer (score 0):

What is the `Partner.number` logic in the update clause? There is no table `Partner.number` declared in the query. This will cause an error.

Try running the command from the MySQL command line so you can see all the errors.

Comment: There's no issue with the query, the result is always a row of data. the problem is that codeigniter won't set the values as it should :/

Comment: Could you double check your procedure code that it is the actual procedure code in the db? There are other errors in it as well (like obscure `C.id` reference) and you should get errors when trying to even trying to creating that.

Comment: Oooohhh my bad, when i was copying the code to the question editor, i forgot to change that C jajajaja, but as i said before, the query works fine, the desired result is the same as the image uploaded. The problem is with the binding of the data.

Comment: done, now the query and the question question are the same. But i still have the issue :/

Comment: Why not show the actual procedure code. The one in the question is not valid (you cannot store it in the database due to errors) and does not even match your output.